# Output a list of AD users, with group names starting with *ABC*

Tags: windows, csv, powershell, active-directory

How can I get a single file(csv or txt) with the name of each group with the members listed underneath.

The groups all start with "ABC" for example.

Here is my code which gives me exactly what I want output to the console, however, when I output to CSV I am not able to append the group name, and only am able to get the members.

```
import-module activedirectory
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -filter {Name -like "ABC*"} | Select-Object Name

ForEach ($Group in $Groups)
   {
    write-host " "
    write-host "$($group.name)"
    Get-ADGroupMember -identity $($group.name) -recursive | Select-Object Name
   }
```

The code above gives me a nice output on the console that's laid out like:

**Group ABC1**

Person1
Person2
Person3
Person4

**Group ABC2**

Person1
Person2
Person3
Person4

How can I have this output into a text or csv file keeps the layout and format as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know why it's not outputting it into your file? Because you are telling it not to.

```
Write-Host "$($group.name)"
```

That will write to the host, your powershell application (ISE or console) and nothing else, because that is what you are telling it to do. Use Write-Output or just put the text on the line alone with quotes around it.

```
import-module activedirectory
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -filter {Name -like "ABC*"} | Select-Object Name

ForEach ($Group in $Groups)
   {
    "`n"|Out-File Somefile.txt -append
    "$($group.name)"|Out-File Somefile.txt -append
    Get-ADGroupMember -identity $($group.name) -recursive | Select-Object Name|Out-File Somefile.txt -append
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipe it to Out-File with the -Append switch.
You can do the same thing with the Write-Host lines, just pipe the output to Out-File with -Append.

Comment: Thanks ! That outputs the layout with the names of the users as shown on the console output, however, I am still missing the group name title above each group of users :(
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the output on the console and also save it in a file:

```
import-module activedirectory
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -filter {Name -like "NU22*"} | Select-Object Name

$null | Set-Content Result.txt

ForEach ($Group in $Groups)
   {
    write-host " "
    $($group.name) | Tee-Object -FilePath Result.txt -Append
    Get-ADGroupMember -identity $($group.name) -recursive | 
    Select-Object Name | Tee-Object -FilePath Result.txt -Append
   }
```